# ProgressBar not in the middle

Tags: android

My code currently looks like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ProgressBar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="518dp"
    android:id="@+id/webview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My ProgressBar is only centered horizontally and not vertically.

I can get it centered in both ways using this code

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
```

but then the the progressbar (or rather spinning) is as big as it can get so it covers the whole screen.

Any solution to this so I can get it centered in the normal height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your `ProgressBar` on the center of the screen and on top of the `WebView`, you need to use a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`, like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="518dp"
        android:id="@+id/webview" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that order matter. (`ProgressBar` after `WebView`)

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it programatically :

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
```

I always made it programatically and worked fine (as expected).